# Android get Facebook friends who have app downloaded

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the Facebook Android SDK. Is there an easy way to get a user's friends who have downloaded the app? For example, the app Draw Something implements this. I can't seem to find any information on this subject

I would guess that if it was possible, some extra information would be needed in the httppost to access this information.

Comment: hey, i too want friends list in a listview. i have used request facebook friends method as in the first part of JPMagalhaes answer below. But i dont know how to habdle the result. I mean how to get the result in a listview. what i am supposed to do with List<GraphUser> users. u can answer it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773639/working-with-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 54, accepted):

*** Note: since 3.14 version, me/friends will only return friends that also use the app, so below implementation is deprecated. See the new "Invitable Friends" or "Taggable Friends" APIs for alternatives.

Using the new **Facebook SDK for Android (3.0)** is very easy to get your user's friend list.
Following is the code:

```
private void requestFacebookFriends(Session session) {
    Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session,
            new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                        Response response) {
                    // TODO: your code for friends here!
                }
            });
}
```

Nevertheless, in order to get the user's friends who are using your Facebook app is a little bit complicated (due to Facebook API documentation). But **yes, it is possible**.

First of all, create your request:

```
private Request createRequest(Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture",
            "installed" };
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

    Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
    parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
    request.setParameters(parameters);

    return request;
}
```

Note that you need to insert the field **"installed"** in your request. I'm requesting the user picture path with the same request. Check your possibilities [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Next, you can use above code to create your request and then get your friends:

```
private void requestMyAppFacebookFriends(Session session) {
    Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
    friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            List<GraphUser> friends = getResults(response);
            // TODO: your code here
        }
    });
    friendsRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

Note that using this generic request, you don't receive a GraphUser list as response. You'll need following code to get the response as GraphUser list:

```
private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
    GraphMultiResult multiResult = response
            .getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
    GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
    return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
}
```

Now you can use your user's friend list, with the information if each of your friends use your Facebook app:

```
GraphUser user = friends.get(0);
boolean installed = false;
if(user.getProperty("installed") != null)
    installed = (Boolean) user.getProperty("installed");
```

Comment: +1 for completeness and correctness, I can't say it better than @BlakeMiller.

Comment: How does the "installed" property works? Does that include users who granted read permissions to the app?

Comment: I'm not sure, @Xylian. What exactly you mean with 'read permissions'?
Following the documentation, installed mean:
"Is the app making the request installed?"

Comment: If you create your app after 30/Apr/2014 , you can only obtain the user's friends who are also using your Facebook app. You are **no longer** able to retrieve the friend list

Comment: @JPMagalhaes - hey, can u plz tell me how to handle result that we get in the first part of your answer. (how to get friends's list in a listview)

Comment: You have to implement an adapter to handle this.

Comment: how can i get all the friends of user ??

Comment: @JPMagalhaes The first code `requestFacebookFriends` doesn't work for me, the packages are missing even if I **do** have the `import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;` set in motion. Could you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: @agiro, this answer is from 2013, last updated in 2014. So I guess this is deprecated. See the new "Invitable Friends" or "Taggable Friends" APIs for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. Pain is, the official FB documentation has lead me astray too :D

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it in this way

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("fields", "name, picture, location, installed");
```

And during displaying of the items on the list,in the getView() method i did this

```
boolean b = jsonObject.getBoolean("installed");

if (b){
    Log.d("VIVEK",jsonObject.getString("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this post helps you:
[How can i get my friends using my facebook App with graph api asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018472/how-can-i-get-my-friends-using-my-facebook-app-with-graph-api-asp-net)

According to the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/), the `has_added_app` field is deprecated and you should use the `is_app_user`

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, so is there no way to make a call to the facebook graph api to get users who are using the app?

Comment: As I found you can execute FQL query to collect this info: 
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {USERS'S FB ID})