# Facebook,Android- How to get friends birthday from facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to goto lots of questions on this forum but could not find one useful so i decided to ask one myself.

I want to pull the birthday's of all the friends in the users friend list.
After going through a lot of stuff i found there are 2 ways to do that

1. Graph API
2. FQL Query

So, my questions are

**Q1.** which one of them is better/easy to integrate in the app.

**Q2.** http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/ is this tutorial useful for what i want to do.

**Q3.** If i use `Graph API/FQL Query` , could you please give me a link which is helpful or a Code snippet

Thanks In Advance,

Eriz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to go for the Graph API as this is usually a more simple approach.

You can check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198965/android-get-facebook-friends-who-have-app-downloaded/15196047#15196047) to see how retrieving a list of friends are completed in API 3.0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the link seems useful, i would like to ask one more thing... what are the other things required in addition to the code on that page?? do i need the authentication page also?

Comment: Yes, I am nearly sure you need to authenticate your identity as information on Facebook is private unlike Twitter.

Check [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) out which provides an official authentication procedure