# working with android alarmmanager

Tags: android

I have a reminder kind of app where users will set their reminders.

Most of the tutorials and example that i found were of alarm manager in which alarm is set up after specific time or at pre defined time. but how can i set it to user entered data and time. Also, there will be more than one alarms set up by the user.

All these are stored in a database and then populated in a lsitview.

This is a fragment in which user will be setting date and time: (texts "dte" and "tme" displays date and time that user has selected) and then when user clicks save button, i want to set alarm at the time that is selected by user.

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
TextView dte,tme, doit;
ImageButton cal;
EditText enteredTask;
Button save;
String taskentered, dateentered, timeentered;
tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_task_fragment, container, false);
    dte = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datetv);
    tme = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timetv);
    Log.d("LifeCycle HirakDebug", "aTF View Created");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("LifeCycle HirakDebug", "aTF Resume");

    enteredTask = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_entered_task);
    doit = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);
    cal = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.select_date);
    save = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.save_tsk);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    cal.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == cal) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        date_time_picker dTP = new date_time_picker();
        dTP.setTargetFragment(this, 1);
        dTP.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.myCustomDialog);
        dTP.show(fm, "dTP");
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "add_task_frag setDate called");
    } else if (view == save) {
        saveData();
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "add_task_frag saveData called");
    }
}

private void saveData() {
    String iidd = null;
    taskentered = enteredTask.getText().toString();
    dateentered = dte.getText().toString();
    timeentered = tme.getText().toString();
    tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(getActivity());
    long id = tasksDatabaseOperations.insertData(iidd, taskentered, dateentered, timeentered);
    if (id < 0) {
        Log.e("HirakDebug", "add_task_frag failed insertData operation");
    } else {
        Log.d("HirakDebug", "Data sent to be inserted");
    }
    tasksDatabaseOperations.sqLiteDatabase.close();
    goBackToTaskListFragment();
}
private void goBackToTaskListFragment() {
    tasksListFrag tLF = new tasksListFrag();
    add_task_frag aTF = new add_task_frag();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
    ft.remove(this);
    ft.replace(R.id.dynamic_content, tLF, "tLF");
    ft.commit();
    Log.d("HirakDebug", "add_task_frag went back to taskListFrag");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1){
        String date = data.getStringExtra("date");
        String time = data.getStringExtra("time");
        dte.setText(date);
        tme.setText(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Repeating Alarm the one you need to use.
Please click on the link below...

Set a Repeating Alarm
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Code example form the link above:

Wake up the device to fire the alarm at precisely 8:30 a.m., and every 20 minutes thereafter:

```html
 private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
 private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
 ...
 alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
 alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

 // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

 // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
 // 20 minutes.
 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
   1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```